# Pinned Shortcuts Minimum API Level in Documentation Incompatible With Code

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.1-nougat, android-api-levels, android-shortcut

as Documentation Says :

> If your app targets Android 7.1 (API level 25) or higher, you can
> define shortcuts to specific actions in your app.
>
> - Pinned shortcuts are
>   published at runtime and also use the ShortcutManager API. During
>   runtime, your app can attempt to pin the shortcut, at which time the
>   user receives a confirmation dialog asking their permission to pin the
>   shortcut. The pinned shortcut appears in supported launchers only if
>   the user accepts the pinning request.  [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts)

So it should be possible to use pinned shortcuts in API level 25 itself and
above, but in the code I get Error that `Calls require API level 26`.

It's happening for all `PinShortcut` Methods like :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1)
            ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
            if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) {
               //do something
            }
}
```

or

`shortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent(pinShortcutInfo);`

these lines of code gets and API Level 26 is required error.

What is the problem? Why Document and SDK say different things?
and how Can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [ShortcutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager) was added in API 25, some of its methods were added later in API 26.

You can see on the documentation that the [isRequestPinShortcutSupported](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager#isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) and [createShortcutResultIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager#createShortcutResultIntent(android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo)) methods were added in API 26.

In other words:

- In API 25 you can enable shortcuts in your app, but the user must add these shortcuts to the homescreen manually if he wants them there.
- In API 26 you can request to add these shortcuts automatically to the homescreen, using those two new methods.

Comment: so in API level 25 we can't create pin shortcut programmatically ?

Comment: No. Only from API 26 and above. You can read about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts#pinned

Comment: it's really bad design :(, Thanks jmart

Comment: @AliZeynali No it's not bad design. It's your fault for using outdated SDKs